# Programmatically insert page break in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, printing, formatting

So I am trying to force a page break while printing directly from my VB.NET program. I am basically using this code from MSDN to print my document:

```
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim charactersOnPage As Integer = 0
    Dim linesPerPage As Integer = 0

    ' Sets the value of charactersOnPage to the number of characters 
    ' of stringToPrint that will fit within the bounds of the page.
    e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, Me.Font, e.MarginBounds.Size, _
        StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charactersOnPage, linesPerPage)

    ' Draws the string within the bounds of the page
    e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, _
    e.MarginBounds, StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

   ' Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
    stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage)

    ' Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
    e.HasMorePages = stringToPrint.Length > 0

End Sub
```

This allows it to print fine, but I would like to put page breaks in specific spots. I've tried e.HasMorePages = true, but I don't understand how this allows me to break at specific locations. Say my stringToPrint is 5000 characters long, and I want to start a new page after 1000 characters, and then again after the next 2500 characters. How would I do this?

Also, changing linesOnPage and charactersOnPage to other values doesn't seem to change anything at all.

EDIT: I guess a little more info about what my program does will help. Basically what it's doing is the program will create about 4 full pages of data, and prints it to a .txt file. Now, I want to print the entire .txt file. The only way that I know how to do this is by printing a string, so I have it read the entire .txt file line by line and stores it all as one string (namely stringToPrint). Now, using the code above, I print stringToPrint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is based on printing to a rectangle: `e.MarginBounds`

For testing, I used this code:

```
Private pageNum As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                          Handles Button1.Click
  Dim sb As New StringBuilder
  For i As Integer = 1 To 100
    sb.AppendLine(i.ToString & ") This is a line.")
  Next
  stringToPrint = sb.ToString

  pageNum = 0
  Using pvw As New PrintPreviewDialog()
    pvw.Document = printDocument1
    pvw.ShowDialog()
  End Using
End Sub
```

Then I changed your routine to use a smaller rectangle on the first page:

```
Private Sub printDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                     ByVal e As PrintPageEventArgs) _
                                     Handles printDocument1.PrintPage
  Dim charactersOnPage As Integer = 0
  Dim linesPerPage As Integer = 0

  pageNum += 1

  Dim printSize As Size = e.MarginBounds.Size
  If pageNum = 1 Then
    printSize = New Size(printSize.Width, printSize.Height / 2)
  End If
  e.Graphics.MeasureString(stringToPrint, Me.Font, printSize, _
      StringFormat.GenericTypographic, charactersOnPage, linesPerPage)

  ' Draws the string within the bounds of the page
  e.Graphics.DrawString(stringToPrint, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, _
    New Rectangle(e.MarginBounds.Location, printSize), _
    StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

  ' Remove the portion of the string that has been printed.
  stringToPrint = stringToPrint.Substring(charactersOnPage)

  ' Check to see if more pages are to be printed.
  e.HasMorePages = stringToPrint.Length > 0
End Sub
```

If you need to control the printing based on characters, you would have to ditch the code that prints the block of text and print everything on a line by line basis.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I will fiddle around with this a bit more, but it definitely is working. The only thing is that my program prints a lot of tables that must be perfectly formatted, so changing things like size and margins really affect it. Just curious, how would you go about changing it to print based on characters instead of box size?

Comment: @IncurableHam I'm not sure I see how you have tables inside a single string variable like `stringToPrint`.  Hard to answer without seeing more of the code, but I would guess having a `List<of Stuff>` to print where you can iterate through a loop and then determine your page breaks based on that.

Comment: Here is what my code to do the actual printing was before:
 e.Graphics.DrawString(stringtoPrint, printFont, Brushes.Black, _
          75, 0, StringFormat.GenericTypographic)

Basically I need those margins (75, 0) for it to print properly. How would I add those to the e.Graphics.Drawstring with the new Rectangle?

Comment: @IncurableHam Something like `New Rectangle(New Point(e.MarginBounds.Left + 75, e.MarginBounds.Top), printSize)`.  Didn't test it.

Comment: @ LarsTech Awesome, thanks! Using that code gave me some other ideas to try and finally this worked: `If page = 1 Then printsize = New Size(printsize.Width + 75, printsize.Height / 2.5)`  
to get what I wanted. I realized that printing in vb.net seems difficult but gives you a lot of room for control if you actually understand it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @IncurableHam Glad to help.  At StackOverflow, it is customary to vote up any helpful answer (and not just to your own posts) and if your question got sufficiently answered, then click the check mark next to that post.

Comment: Ok thanks, I couldn't upvote yet because I don't have 15 reputation. One last question: With this way of printing, are the MarginBounds somehow relient on the specific printer it is going to print to? I read somewhere that it is, but I don't understand why. If it is, is there a way to make it so it doesn't rely on printer settings?

Comment: @IncurableHam Pretty sure it is.  Different printers have different page sizes, so if you are printing to a particular printer, it would make a lot of sense for the printer to conveniently tell you how much space is available on the page.

Comment: So is it possible to make it so that the formatting will be the same on each printer? I need page breaks that will be in the same spot on any printer because this program will mostly be used on printers other than mine

Comment: @IncurableHam As long as the page breaks aren't too close to the bottom edge, I would think it would be fine.  The real estate differences between printers printing an 8 1/2 by 11 page paper is very minor.